# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+y^2+x^2}{x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, substitution

Suppose I didn't know to begin with that $y=x\tan x$ satisfies the differential equation below; how I would I go about solving this differential equation?

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+y^2+x^2}{x}$$
It seems very unlikely that I can use some clever manipulation to convert this into a differential equation that can be solved by separating the variables, and I also don't think that I'd be able to use the integrating factor method here.

The only thing that comes to mind as possibly useful is to use some substitution, but I cannot yet see any substitution that is useful.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use $y = xv$ to homogenize the right side (i.e. $y^2+x^2 = x^2(1+v^2))$

$$y' = v+xv' = \frac{xv+x^2v^2+x^2}{x} = v + x(1+v^2)$$

$$\implies v' = 1+v^2$$

which has the solution $v = \tan(x+C)$ by separation of variables

Comment: +1 That's really lovely, thanks! What do you mean by homogenizing (if that's a word) the right hand side?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent i.e. means "that is"

Comment: I know that, thanks :) I just don't understand the meaning of the words 'to homogenize'.

Comment: ...the definition is given after the ie. In speech the formula goes "unknown term. That is, [insert meaning]"

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear. The definition of to homegenize is to make $y^2+x^2=x^2(1+v^2)$? Surely there is a more general meaning?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent it comes from the phrase "homogeneous property" you will see most commonly in one of two places: a norm axiom $$||\lambda x|| = |\lambda|\cdot ||x||$$ and homogeneous functions $$f(\lambda x_1, \cdots , \lambda x_n) = \lambda^n f(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$$ These aren't "rigorous definitions" but part of the parlance you should know in mathematics. There is always a good reason in math why similarly named concepts are similarly named, keep that in mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119875/discussion-between-a-level-student-and-ninad-munshi).

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+y^2+x^2}{x}$$
$$xy'={y+y^2+x^2}$$
$$xy'-y=y^2+x^2$$
$$\left (\dfrac yx \right)'=1+\dfrac {y^2}{x^2}$$
$$d\left (\dfrac yx \right)=\left(1+\dfrac {y^2}{x^2} \right) dx$$
This is separable.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is wonderful!

Comment: You're very welcome @A-LevelStudent